# Не отображаются картинки на localhost

Tags: php, xampp

Подключаю header с помощью include_once из index

header находится в другой папке и путь картинок таков:
[image]

На localhost(XAMPP) картинки не грузятся, однако на хосте все работает. В чем может быть причина?

Answer (score 1):

Указывайте пути к ресурсам относительно корня домена. К примеру если в корне сайта есть директория images, а в ней находятся все изображения, тогда путь должен быть следующий:

```
<img src="/images/symbol-st.svg" alt="Logo M3ST">
```

Comment: Работает, только если убрать ../. Но тогда почему, без изменения путей, работает на хосте?